# How to sort a file with timestamp having date and time

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file having data like,

```
[2/6/20 10:07:26:877 IST] a
[2/6/20 11:39:09:575 IST] b
[2/6/20 12:26:05:689 IST] c
[2/6/20 14:08:05:583 IST] d
[2/6/20 15:19:51:719 IST] e
[2/5/20 15:19:51:719 IST] i
[2/6/20 18:16:19:771 IST] f
[2/6/20 2:19:51:757 IST] g
[2/6/20 8:16:59:420 IST] h
```

I want to sort the file based on the timestamp. I have tried the below command,

```
cat file | sort -k1 

[2/5/20 15:19:51:719 IST] i
[2/6/20 10:07:26:877 IST] a
[2/6/20 11:39:09:575 IST] b
[2/6/20 12:26:05:689 IST] c
[2/6/20 14:08:05:583 IST] d
[2/6/20 15:19:51:719 IST] e
[2/6/20 18:16:19:771 IST] f
[2/6/20 2:19:51:757 IST] g
[2/6/20 8:16:59:420 IST] h
```

But the result is not correct. Some timestamps are not in the correct order. How to sort the file in the right manner?

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I have already shared my efforts. Edited the question a bit for better understanding..!

Comment: With GNU sort `sort -M  Input_file` this has worked for me fine, can you please check it once?

Comment: sort -M is not working.Its giving the same output as shown above

Comment: With GNU sort version of `8.221` it works fine for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort logs by date field in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242986/sort-logs-by-date-field-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n,2n
```

worked perfectly fine!