# Fetch latest version of postgresql version from the postgresql artifacoty using shell script (centos environment)

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, xml-parsing, centos

I want to fetch the name of the latest tar file uploaded on PostgreSQL artifactory and want to automate the same process.

I am referring to : https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/

I am extracting an XML to parse from above URL

XML file looks something like this:

```html
<html>
<head><title>Index of /pub/odbc/versions/src/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /pub/odbc/versions/src/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
    <a href="psqlodbc-11.00.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-11.00.0000.tar.gz</a>                         17-Nov-2018 13:50              918461
    <a href="psqlodbc-11.01.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-11.01.0000.tar.gz</a>                         24-May-2019 14:28              919372
    <a href="psqlodbc-12.00.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-12.00.0000.tar.gz</a>                         11-Oct-2019 14:14              920713
    <a href="psqlodbc-12.01.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-12.01.0000.tar.gz</a>                         07-Jan-2020 13:53              932672
    <a href="psqlodbc-12.02.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-12.02.0000.tar.gz</a>                         26-May-2020 13:01              937847
    <a href="psqlodbc-13.00.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-13.00.0000.tar.gz</a>                         19-Nov-2020 09:53              940031
    <a href="psqlodbc-13.01.0000.tar.gz">psqlodbc-13.01.0000.tar.gz</a>                         02-May-2021 12:27              941064
    <a href="psqlodbc-7.2.3.tar.gz">psqlodbc-7.2.3.tar.gz</a>                                   16-Oct-2002 09:09              367168
    <a href="psqlodbc-7.2.4.tar.gz">psqlodbc-7.2.4.tar.gz</a>                                   12-Nov-2002 08:41              406385
    <a href="psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz">psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz</a>                                   29-Nov-2002 16:10              415885
</pre></hr></body>
</html>
```

I want to fetch the latest version uploaded on the XML based on the date modified.

I tried

xmllint --xpath "string(//a[last()]/text())" myfile.xml

But it is giving output : psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz (This is not what i want)

I want output to be : psqlodbc-13.01.0000.tar.gz (since it was modified latest on 02-May-2021 12:27)

Found a workaround:

```
artifactCount=$(xmllint --xpath "count(//a)" psql.xml)

latestModified="20010101"

for (( i=2; i<=${artifactCount}; i++ ))
do
  dateModified=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//pre/text()[$i])" psql.xml)
  dateModified=$(echo ${dateModified} | awk '{$NF="";sub(/[ \t]+$/,"")}1')
  dateModified=$(echo ${dateModified} | awk '{$NF="";sub(/[ \t]+$/,"")}1')
  dateModified=$(date -d "$dateModified" +%Y%m%d)
  
  if [ ${dateModified} -gt ${latestModified} ]
    then
        latestModified=${dateModified}
        j=${i}
    fi 
done

psqlfile=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//a[${j}]/text())" psql.xml)

echo "Latest file found : ${psqlfile} modified on ${latestModified} "

psqlversion=${psqlfile#"psqlodbc-"}
psqlversion=${psqlversion%".tar.gz"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([a-zA-Z]\{3\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1 \2 \3/' myfile.xml | sort -k5,5 -k4,4M -k3,3 -k6,6 | grep -oP '(?<=">).*(?=<)' | tail -1
```

First, use `sed` format the file's date like **17-Nov-2018** replace `-` to blank for then sort by `sort -k`.

Then use [`sort -k`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/trying-to-sort-on-two-fields-second-then-first) by the order: [*year, month, day, time*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242986/sort-logs-by-date-field-in-bash).

Last use `grep` and `tail` to scratch the last file name.

The other way, I found the last column like **941064**, is also sort by order, so it works only use this command:

```
sort -k5,5 myfile.xml | grep -oP '(?<=">).*(?=<)' | tail -1
```

Answer (score 2):

`xmllint` can't open urls and only supports XPath 1.0, last I checked. I'd suggest you give [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) a try.

```
$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e 'x:lines(//pre)'
../
psqlodbc-07.03.0100.tar.gz                        15-May-2003 15:56             446075
psqlodbc-07.03.0200.tar.gz                        22-Oct-2003 13:46             451263
[...]
psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz                             29-Nov-2002 16:10             415885

$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e '
  x:lines(//pre)[position() gt 1]
'
psqlodbc-07.03.0100.tar.gz                        15-May-2003 15:56             446075
psqlodbc-07.03.0200.tar.gz                        22-Oct-2003 13:46             451263
psqlodbc-08.00.0100.tar.gz                        02-Mar-2005 14:35             586241
[...]
psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz                             29-Nov-2002 16:10             415885
```

*([`x:lines()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-lines) is a shorthand for `tokenize(...,'\r\n?|\n')` and turns the input into a sequence where every new line is another item)*

```
$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e '
  x:lines(//pre)[last()] ! tokenize(.,"\s{2,}")
'
psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz
29-Nov-2002 16:10
415885

$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e '
  x:lines(//pre)[last()] ! parse-ietf-date(tokenize(.,"\s{2,}")[2])
'
2002-11-29T16:10:00Z
```

```
$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e '
  for $release in x:lines(//pre)[position() gt 1]
  order by parse-ietf-date(tokenize($release,"\s{2,}")[2])
  return $release
'
psqlodbc-7.2.3.tar.gz                             16-Oct-2002 09:09             367168
psqlodbc-7.2.4.tar.gz                             12-Nov-2002 08:41             406385
psqlodbc-7.2.5.tar.gz                             29-Nov-2002 16:10             415885
[...]
psqlodbc-13.01.0000.tar.gz                        02-May-2021 12:27             941064

$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e '
  (
    for $release in x:lines(//pre)[position() gt 1]
    order by parse-ietf-date(tokenize($release,"\s{2,}")[2])
    return $release
  )[last()]
'
psqlodbc-13.01.0000.tar.gz                        02-May-2021 12:27             941064

$ xidel -s https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/ -e '
  resolve-uri(
    (
      for $release in x:lines(//pre)[position() gt 1]
      let $item:=tokenize($release,"\s{2,}")
      order by parse-ietf-date($item[2])
      return $item[1]
    )[last()]
  )
'
https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/src/psqlodbc-13.01.0000.tar.gz
```