# Sort lines in a file based on timestamp

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a text file with the following format. Is there a way to sort the data based on date/time and write it to another file. I know a way using python, but intend to use bash only for this.

```
15:19 09/01/21 string1
2:19 09/01/21 string2
1:19 09/01/21 string3
```

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243126/418599 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a Schwartzian transform like so:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 file |
date -f - +%s          |
paste - file           |
sort -n                |
cut -f 2-
```